# I can not get the json values for loop in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I'm new to swift. I received a json I want to break into the value of this for loop. My code is below.

```
func test(){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "url", parameters:nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                //print(response.result.value!["headers"]!!["Accept"])
                let mansetArray = response.result.value!["mansetler"] as! NSArray

                for var i = 0; i < mansetArray.count; ++i {
                    let item = mansetArray[i] as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let name = item!["news_title"] as? [String: AnyObject] //eror 
                    print(item)  //print: nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil
                }

            }
    }
}
```

format as:

```
{ }JSON
    [ ]mansetler
     { } 0
         news_id : "value1"
         news_title : "value2"
         news_photo_headline : "value3"
         headline_category_title : "value4"
         news_date : "09 June 2016, Thursday"
         news_readed_count : "36"
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `let name = item!"news_title" ]as? [String: AnyObject]` instead? (I don't know about the "!" and the "?" since I'm not familiar with Swift, but it seems weird to pass the value as the key. But you need to explain what's not working exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following changes.

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]
```

typecast objects as per your JSON

```
let name = item!["news_title"] as? String
```